# AlertDialog.Builder not a Statement

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-alertdialog

i have a Problem with my Android Project,

```
AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(testActivity.this);
Error:(183, 30) error: not a statement
Error:(183, 38) error: ';' expected
```

`import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;` is Grey, "Unused import Statement"

```
label422: AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder15 = new AlertDialog.Builder(testActivity.this);
        localBuilder15.setTitle("Test!");
        localBuilder15.setMessage("Test Save");
        localBuilder15.setIcon(2130837510);
        localBuilder15.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
          {
            Toast.makeText(testActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "Test wird gespeichert!", 0).show();
            TestActivity.this.result = TestActivity.this.abfrage;
            new TestActivity.SaveProductDetails(TestActivity.this).execute(new String[0]);
          }
        });
        localBuilder3.setNegativeButton("Ohne Änderung speichern", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
          {
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "test wird nicht gespeichert!", 0).show();
            TestActivity.this.result = TestActivity.this.txtSafe.getText().toString();
            new TestActivity.SaveProductDetails(TestActivity.this).execute(new String[0]);
          }
        });
        localBuilder15.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

A label can precede only a statement, not a declaration.

Since in this statement you both declare and initialize a variable, it is considered a declaration, not a statement, so the label becomes illegal.

If you want to put a label on the part of the line that is currently the initialization, you should use:

```
AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder15;
label422: localBuilder15 = new AlertDialog.Builder(testActivity.this);
```

This way, your label marks a statement, not a declaration.

But of course, as you have already been told, the label is simply superfluous here. If you don't have any `break` statements within your statement, it's simply not useful.

Note:

- There is no `goto` in Java, so labels can't be used as jump targets.
- If you want to break to a label, the label has to mark a statement that encloses the block containing the `break` statement. The statement marked by the label is always just the one that follows it up to the next `;`, or if the label marks a compound statement, its ending `}`. So the label you created only marks the `new` statement, and no `break` statement in the statements after that will be in its scope.